# Problems displaying code with js and underscore.js

Tags: javascript, json, underscore.js, display

I have this code below and I want to use undercorejs in order to display the text from the json file.  I need to modify the section, as it seen below the comment, to be like that:

I have tried to duplicate it but it causes errors and does not display anything. Any suggestions? Sorry, if that's a silly question but im new to programming.

> hold.options (tooltips object) = {
>        (property based on the section generated automatically): {
>         (properly based on the itemName generated automatically): {
>              t: item.Texts,
>           }
>         }

```
var log = function(contents) {
  if (_.isArray(contents)) {
    _.each(contents, function(e, i, l) {
      log(e);
      $('#result');
      $('#result').append('</br></br>');
    });
  } else {
    $('#result').append(contents);
  }
};

var ty = [{
  "Language": "en-GB",
  "Section": "Sales&Marketing",
  "ItemName": "CalculationType",
  "Texts": "Having selected the account heading select the calculation ..."
}, {
  "Language": "en-GB",
  "Section": "Taxes",
  "ItemName": "Save",
  "Texts": "The Master Tax Table has been pre populated with the current UK, ..."
}];
var out = [];
_.each(ty, function(item, key) {
  var hold = {};

//Part that needs to change
  hold.options = {
    Taxes: {
      Save: {
        t: item.Texts,
      }
    }
  };
  out.push(hold)
});
_.each(out, function(item) {
  log(item.options.Taxes.Save.t + '<br>');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbv1o75f/33/)

```
//Part that needs to change
  hold.options = {};
  hold.options[item.Section] = {};
  hold.options[item.Section][item.ItemName] = {t: item.Texts};
  out.push(hold)
});
_.each(out, function(item) {
  if(item.options.Sales !== undefined && item.options.Sales.Type !== undefined){
    log(item.options.Sales.Type.t); 
  }
  else if(item.options.Taxes !== undefined && item.options.Taxes.Save !== undefined){
    log(item.options.Taxes.Save.t);
  }
```

Comment: the code i posted works.. it's when im modifying it to be similar to the yellow box above that it doesn't work!

Comment: So how exactly are you modifying it and what happens then? You can use my Codepen to show the exact problem.

Comment: it must follow this format --> hold.options (tooltips object) = { (property based on the section generated automatically): { (properly based on the itemName generated automatically): { t: item.Texts,
} }

Comment: So please tell what you tried and what kind of errors you encountered.

Comment: sorry, i just seen the changes you made on the codepen, but they don't work... they don't display anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148306/discussion-between-george-x-replay-and-k-kirsz).

Comment: can you join the chat please so I can explain you in real time?